# How to Hide Iframe if web browser size is reduced or in windowed mode

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, iframe

I'm trying to make an Iframe hidden if the screen size is smaller than the width of the IFrame. Right now if I'm using a small laptop the side of the website has a white line (see pic below) and I would just like to hide the Iframe if the screen size or web browser is too small.

Here is my code, it seems to work with mobile devices, but when I resize my web browser it doesn't  hide.

```
       <iframe embed class="v-tour-object" style=position:absolute;left:700px;top:0px; width="550" height="360"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>

<script>
 if(window.innerWidth <= 1000 && window.innerHeight <= 800) {
   document.querySelector('.v-tour-object').style.display = "none"
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Use `Media Query` OR `window.addEventListener("resize", () => {...});`, Set `display: none`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I'm new to coding where would I put the window.addeventlistener in my code and how would I put where do I put the sizes? (below Is how I added it but it does seem to be correct)

   window.addEventListener("resize", () => {1000,800});, Set display: none

Comment: you can try use this css ...........  


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { .v-tour-object { display: none; } }

Comment: Use it inside `script block`: <script></script>

Comment: Still showing the white line and displaying the video. 

<iframe embed class="v-tour-object" style=position:absolute;left:700px;top:0px; width="550" height="360"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY" >
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { .v-tour-object { display: none; } }
</style>
</iframe>

Answer (score 1):

You should handle `window resize` event

**OR**

Css `Media Query`

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    const h = window.innerHeight;

    if (h < 920) document.querySelector(".v-tour-object").style.display = "none";
});
```

**Css**

```css
@media only screen and (max-height: 920px) {
    .v-tour-object {
        didplay: none;
    }
}
```